# FHIR : resource for device software installation file

Tags: hl7-fhir

I would like to manage in FHIR a software installation file for a medical device, in order to get the last available version and dowload it. Could it be done with the "Binary Resource" and how (which RESTful query to make to get the last version for a specific Device model) ? Or do I need to create my own resource using the resource "Other".

Thanks for you responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the binary resource is appropriate. Assuming that the FHIR server supports versioning, then you just ask it for the latest binary resource and it returns the resource (software installation file) along with the HTTP `Content-Location`.  The value of the `Content-Location` contains the version number, which you can then compare against the version that is currently installed.

```
GET [base]/Binary/my-device

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Last-Modified: Thu, 24 Apr 2013 00:41:55 +1200
Content-Location: http://[base]/Binary/my-device/_history/4
```

The version number, 4 in this case, is the last component of the `Content-Location`.

As you can see the server will also return the date and time that the software installation file was updated in the HTTP `Last-Modified` header.  It might be easier to use this instead of relying upon a version number.

If you decide to use a date based version, then you can just ask the FHIR server to return all installation files since your last update.  Note, that you should add 1 second to your last update date because FHIR treats the `_since` query parameter as inclusive.

```
GET [base]/Binary/my-device?_since=2013-04-24T00:41:56+1200
```

The above returns a bundle of software installation files since your last update, which is most instances will contain no entries because your device is up to date.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to manage different kinds of binary in my system. The latest binary resource is not necessarily a software installation file but maybe a CDA document or a PDF. Is is possible to distinguish and manage different types of binaries ? I think it's not possible because there is only one entry point to binary resource without no possible paramaters.

Comment: Sorry, but this was not in you question.  I would propose that the binary resource is then a ZIP file of all your files (software installation, CDA, PDF, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be binary. Not quite sure what the context or the use case is

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that with binary, there are no query parameter possible. Here is my scenario : the server stores all the software installation files available for a specific medical device. My client application will ask the server which is the last software version for a specific device and then will download the installation file for this version. So I need an intermediate "software version" resource, which can be linked to the binary. But I don't know which standard FHIR resource to use to represent my software version information.

Comment: Well, this is far outside the expected scope of FHIR, but ok. It sounds like a binary with an extension to device to link to the binary to me